# Change Job Description or Job Log on iSeries Access ODBC DB2 iSeries

Tags: db2, odbc, ibm-midrange

I am using iSeries Access ODBC Driver on a Linux Centos server to access as/400 using PHP/PDO.

When a webpage makes a ODBC query, it writes to the joblog on QZDASOINIT.

Are there any ODBC.ini settings which can be used to disable writing to the joblog, changing the job description or server program used?  It is flooding the log, and it is hard to find important legacy related QZDASOINIT jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm on 7.1.  My QZDASOINIT jobs run with job description QDFTSVR, which is set to LOG(4 0 *NOLIST).  I don't get job logs unless the server jobs fall over.  Look at the jobs whilst they are active and see what job description they are using.  Also, check to see if the jobs are ending abnormally (and that is why you're getting job logs).

Comment: The actions seemed not to have any errors.  I noticed on Windows ODBC setup there's a "Print job log at disonnect".  I found in the second response a Trace = 0, I'm hoping that helps.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: Turns out the Trace=0 did nothing.  Also the job logs are not errors, they are blank.

Comment: I was wondering what your QHST file looks like? Does it have a CPIAD09 message for every ODBC query?

Comment: I get a CPIAD09 User WEBUSER from client 10.1.0.1 connected to job 906025/QUSER/QZDASOINIT for each connection.  A given connection can serve many ODBC queries.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am seeing them every connection.  I'm trying to enable connection pooling and/or persistence in order to reduce the number of connection requests, but have not yet been successful.

Comment: You should start a new question rather than ask followups in comments.  When you do, post some code and maybe even one of the job logs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on 6.1 and our QZDASOINIT jobs run with job description QGPL/QDFTJOBD and our log settings are level 4, severity 0 and text = *NOLIST (just like Buck's).

The only thing that shows up in our job logs though are things like "File XYZ in library ABC already exists" when a program is called, executing queries doesn't cause anything to be written to the job log.

Here's my odbc.ini

```
[primary]
Description             = primary
Driver                  = iSeries Access ODBC Driver
System                  = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
UserID                  = xxxxxxxxxx
Password                = xxxxxxxxxx
Naming                  = 0
DefaultLibraries        = QGPL
Database                = xxxxxxxxxx
ConnectionType          = 0
CommitMode              = 2
ExtendedDynamic         = 0
DefaultPkgLibrary       = QGPL
DefaultPackage          = A/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512
AllowDataCompression    = 1
LibraryView             = 0
AllowUnsupportedChar    = 0
ForceTranslation        = 0
Trace                   = 0
```

and my odbcinst.ini

```
[iSeries Access ODBC Driver]
Description     = iSeries Access for Linux ODBC Driver
Driver          = /usr/lib/libcwbodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libcwbodbcs.so
NOTE1           = If using unixODBC 2.2.11 or later and you want the 32 and 64-bit ODBC drivers to share DSN's,
NOTE2           = the following Driver64/Setup64 keywords will provide that support.
Driver64        = /usr/lib/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading       = 2
DontDLClose     = 1
UsageCount      = 1
```

And my connection string:

```
$this->db_connection = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=10.xxx.xxx.xxx;PROTOCOL=TCPIP", $temp_username, $temp_password);
```

I'm not aware of any settings in odbc.ini or odbcinst.ini you can make that will affect logging on the IBM i, I think you'll need to change something on the i itself like the job description of the user you are connecting with.

Comment: I noticed the Trace = 0 in there, and did a search.  I found Trace: Allows the sequence of function calls made by an ODBC application to be recorded into a log file.  I set it to 0 and will check to see if that helped.

Comment: To turn *ON* ODBC tracing you have to set Trace = 1. Trace = 0 turns tracing off which is the default. You'll also want to add TraceFile = /tmp/odbc.log (or some other directory/filename) and put it in the odbcinst.ini file.

Comment: I was wondering what your QHST file looks like?  Does it have a CPIAD09 message for every ODBC query?

Comment: @JohnLee - I have left my previous employer and no longer do any development so I'm afraid I can't answer your question :-(